ERROR - Cannot find 'Podrozmaitosci_2.bcf'! INFO - ERRORS: 1
I can't find the solution for my TexMaker. I saved this document from the origin (using save as...) and It's the first compilation with the error. I don't know how I can solve it in my TexMaker.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep} %do druku dwustronnego proszę dodać twoside
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\graphicspath{{jpg/}{png/}}
%\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}



% otoczenia dla twierdzeń
\newtheorem{tw}{Twierdzenie}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemat}[chapter]
\newtheorem{wns}{Wniosek}[chapter]

% otoczenia dla definicji i przykładów
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{przkl}{Przykład}[chapter]
\newtheorem{defn}[tw]{Definicja}

% otoczenie dla uwagi
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{uwg}[tw]{Uwaga}


% definicje zbiorów liczbowych
\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}% liczby rzeczywiste
\def\NN{\mathbb{N}}% liczny naturalne
\def\CC{\mathbb{C}}% liczby zespolone
\def\QQ{\mathbb{Q}}% liczny wymierne

%zbiór pusty
\usepackage{amssymb}

\let\oldemptyset\emptyset
\let\emptyset\varnothing
\DeclareMathOperator\supp{supp}
\DeclareMathOperator\codim{codim}
\DeclareMathOperator{\spn}{span}


\begin{document}
\baselineskip18pt
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\textsc{Uniwersytet Jana Kochanowskiego w Kielcach\\
Wydział Nauk Ścisłych i Przyrodniczych}\vspace{12pt}




This is my bibliography:
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{MA} M.Adachi, \emph{Embedding and Immersions}, American Mathematical Society, 1984.
\bibitem{AW} A. Wasserman, \emph{The Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem}, online LENT, 2010.\bibitem{E} R.Engelking, \emph{Topologia ogólna}, PWN, Warszawa, 2007.
\bibitem{MJ} J.Milnor, \emph{Lectures on the h-cobordism theorem}, Princeton University Press, 1993.
\bibitem{MP} M.Persson, \emph{The Whitney embedding theorem}, UMEA University, 2014.
\bibitem{JL} J.Lawson, \emph{Differential Geometry}, Louisiana State University, 2006, \url{https://www.math.lsu.edu/~lawson/Chapter1.pdf}
\bibitem{ZM} Z.Smith Embedding and Immersion.  Chicago University.  2019. dostępny w Internecie pod linkiem: https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2019/REUPapers/Smith,Zoe.pdf
\bibitem{MG} M.Gualtieri, \emph{Topology 1, Smooth manifolds}, University of Toronto, 2016, \url{http://www.math.toronto.edu/mgualt/courses/MAT1300F-2016/}
\bibitem{SL} S.Lu, \emph{Isometric Embedding of Riemannian manifolds}, 2012.
\bibitem{ZW} Zuoqin Wang The Whitney Embedding Theorem. Chapter 9. University of Science and Technology of China \url{http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/18F-Manifolds/Notes/Lec09.pdf}.a
\bibitem{MZ} M.Zakrzewski, \emph{Notatki do seminarium dyplomowego}.
\bibitem{GP} V.Gullemin,  A. Pollack Differential Topology.  1974 New Jersey. \url{https://www.cimat.mx/~gil/docencia/2020/topologia_diferencial/%5BGuillemin,Pollack%5DDifferential_Topology(1974).pdf}
\end{thebibliography}


Welcome! Your document is incomplete. But the error seems to be from Biber. It seems the .bcf wasn't written. I don't know what the class you're using does, but you don't seem to have loaded Biblatex or set up a bibliography.

I added my bibliography, maybe it helps

You don't need to run biber because you're explicitly coding the bibliography. Just don't run biber and compile a couple of times and it will be fine. If your editor is automatically running biber, change what it is doing. (Pick a different compilation setting or change the defaults.)
